# Conservation of mechanical energy on spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, spring, free-body-diagram

[image]

Suppose the mass moves from compressed position to stretched position as shown in the figure. Then by applying mechanical energy conservation at stretched position what is the cause for the bulid up of kinetic energy? Is it the loss of potential energy from going from compressed to equilibrium?

Comment: -1 Not clear why you doubt the answer which you have given to your own question.

Comment: @sammygerbil  That was  not the answer.......I just gave my guess on the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the compressed condition, the spring applies a force on the block towards the equilibrium position due to the deformation caused by an external agent. The external agent does some work to cause this deformation which is stored as the spring's initial potential energy.

$$ Potential\space energy \implies Deformation \implies Spring\space Force$$

The spring force is the agent that does the work on the block. This is the only force that exists in this case and it only comes into the picture when there is some deformation. For a deformation of '$x$' units from the equilibrium position, the spring force is given as,

$${\vec{F}}_{spring}=-k\vec{x}$$

When you (external agent) let go of the block, the spring force does positive work on the block at expense of the initial potential energy.

At the eqm. position, the potential energy of the spring is zero. But the initial potential energy must have gone somewhere. The spring's potential energy has been exhausted and completely converted into kinetic energy of the block. This is what energy conservation says.

If there is net force, there is acceleration.  However, it doesn't necessarily mean that if a force is acting on a body, the body will always have non-zero speed. The force could be acting in the direction opposite to the direction of initial motion and keep depleting the body's kinetic energy and finally bringing it to rest and begin accelerating the body in its own direction. This is exactly what happening here.

The block, after reaching equilibrium, due to its kinetic energy will get past the eqm. position. When this happens, the spring starts getting extended and spring force comes into the picture again.

But this time spring force does negative work and this work takes away the kinetic energy and completely transform it into potential energy.

$$W_{spring}=-\Delta U=\Delta KE$$

When the spring does positive work, potential energy gets converted into kinetic energy and when the spring does negative work, kinetic energy gets converted into potential energy. This is the nature of conservative forces.

$$W_{conservative}=-\Delta U$$

More generally, when conservative forces, like spring force, do positive work the potential energy of the system decreases. Similarly, when they do negative work the potential energy of the system increases. This is evident from the above relation.

Comment: SO when we apply mechanical energy conservation between compressed and stretched part,will we have to include this kinetic enrgy as a part of the equation

Comment: Yes, we will have to do that. The work energy theorem considers all the work by different forces in the left hand side of the equation and the net change in kinetic energy in the right hand side of the equation. Change is potential energy is nothing but negative of work by spring force (or conservative force is general). In the absence of non-conservative forces, you can replace $W_{spring}$ by $-\Delta U$ and modify the work energy theorem as $\Delta KE + \Delta U =0$.

Comment: For example, if you apply energy conservation at two extremes of the spring i.e, at the maximum compression and maximum extension, you have zero kinetic energy. Therefore, $\Delta U + \Delta KE = 0$ but for our case $\Delta KE= 0$. Which implies, $\Delta U = 0$. This means that at both the opposite extremes, potential energy will be the same. But between these two extremes, kinetic energy won't be zero. So you will have to find the $\Delta$ KE first, if you want to find $\Delta U$ and vice versa.

Comment: So in order to apply mechanical energy conservation,we have to know the kinetic enrgy change as well as potential energy change ....That's why we cant apply this theorem randomly,right?

Answer (score -4):

The loss is cause by mass in the atoms when expanding from the compressed state and returning from the stretched out state resulting in an equilibrium. The more compressed it is the more massive it is and you are just releasing mass's force when not held down. Not energy just mass.